# Xcode 11 Swift 5 CryptoKit share SymmetricKey

Tags: swift, xcode, share, symmetric-key

I'm starting to learn de-/encrypting with the CryptoKit. 
Everything works fine, but I can not share my generated SymmetricKey.

Example:

```
let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
```

Well, I generate a symmetric key. Now I want to share the key, but how I can do that? 
Inside the debugger the variable *key* is empty? 
I check the encryption and decryption - works well - output shows the encrypted and decrypted data. How can I save my variable *key* for distribution?

I found a solution:

```
let savedKey = key.withUnsafeBytes {Data(Array($0)).base64EncodedString()}
```

This works great, but how can I save the variable *savedKey* (String) back into the variable *key* (SymmetricKey)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that by converting key string to `Data` and retrieve the key from it

```
let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
let savedKey = key.withUnsafeBytes {Data(Array($0)).base64EncodedString()}

if let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: savedKey) {
    let retrievedKey = SymmetricKey(data: keyData)
}
```

Hope this helps :)